# String similarity between two vectors of words

Tags: python, semantics

I have two very long O(100k) list of words and I need to find all similar pairs. My solution has a time complexity of O(n*m). Is it a way to optimize this algorithm - reduce its complexity?

```
def are_similar(first, second):
    threshold = 0.88
    return difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=first.lower(), b=second.lower()).ratio() > threshold


list_1 = ["123456","23456",  ...] # len(list_1) ~ 100k
list_2 =["123123","asda2131", ...] # len(list_2)~ 500k

similar = []
for element_list1 in list_1:
    for element_list2 in list_2:
        if are_similar(element_list1,element_list2 ):
            similar.append((element_list1,element_list2 ))

print (similar)
```

What is the best way to parallelize above code? My current implementation, not included, uses multiprocessing.Pool over the first loop.

Comment: Just curious, is `are_similar` symmetric? That is `are_similar(x, y) == are_similar (y, x)`?

Comment: @Elmex80s yes, it is symmetric.

Comment: Not a solution but a nit, you're not actually calculating the semantic similarity of two lists with this method. This in no way captures the _meaning_ of the two pieces of text and whether they are similar.

Comment: @NickChapman you are right. I edited the topic name.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest another solution but I am not sure if you want exactly the same thing I am suggesting.
First, there are two `lists`, if we match one element of a list with itself, similarity is `1` i.e. exact match. So, we may start with next word to compare. Now, lets take all the words in single list by taking set of lists.

```
list_1 = ["123456","23456",  ...] # len(list_1) ~ 100k
list_2 =["123123","asda2131", ...] # len(list_2)~ 500k


list_3 = list_1 + list_2
list_3 = list(set(list_3)) # this will merge all same words to a list of unique words.
similar = []
for i in range(0, len(list_3)):
    if are_similar(list_3[i], list_3[i+1]):
        similar.append((list_3[i],list_3[i+1]))

print (similar)
```

I took here list of set of `list of words` to compare since if we may compare exactly same words again and again and hence, we reduce significantly number of comparisons on repeated words. The complexity of this method is `O(n)`. I hope this may help.